# In Terragrunt, include a specific Terraform module iff a file exists in the terragrunt working directory

Tags: terraform, terragrunt

I have a terraform module that I would like to include in the build process if and only if there is a certain file in the current terragrunt working directory.

Example:

Terragrunt working dirs:

- config/dev/foo/

  - terragrunt.hcl
  - config.yaml
- config/dev/bar/

  - terragrunt.hcl
  - config.yaml
  - additional.yaml

Terraform working dirs:

- infrastructure/

  - foo/
  - bar/
  - additional/

In the `bar` case (terragrunt working in config/dev/bar) I would like to include the infrastructure/additional module in the deployment and also pass certain variables to the module.

Is that possible? If yes, how do I do that?

I've asked ChatGPT already but it came up with a non-viable solution (plain wrong).

Answer (score 0):

Terragrunt by design does not have such functionality. Each "terragrunt.hcl" config file downloads a single Terraform module specified in "source".

On the other hand, you could create a root Terraform module that includes configuration for all your modules. There you can have a condition for "additional" module. Something like

```
module "foo" {...}

module "additional" {
    for_each = var.create_additional_module ? [true] : []
    source = "./additional"
}
```

Finally, you can reference this root module as your source in Terragrunt.

There are multiple options for a condition in for_each block (e.g. fileexists function https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/fileexists), however at the end of the day it needs to be handled inside a Terraform module.

More info on for_each - https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/meta-arguments/for_each